# Image selection canvas

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, button

Acutally i'm doing a WPF application where user can select `Image` from a panel. There are two `Button` inside the panel (right arrow and left arrow). I'm not sure what is the name of the panel but i attach an image in my question. So, i want to ask how do i create the panel? Using a canvas and put the image inside the canvas? hm... and the buttons, I totally don't have any ideal how to do it.

p/s: i'm wpf newbie

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, using the standard ListBox control:

First, we need a pair of Previous/Next buttons and a ListBox. We make the ListBox lay out its items horizontally by changing its ItemsPanel:

```
<DockPanel Width="200" >
    <Button x:Name="_prev" Content="&lt;&lt;" />
    <Button x:Name="_next" Content="&gt;&gt;" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />

    <ListBox x:Name="_myList" Loaded="OnMyListLoaded" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <TextBlock Text="Image1  " />
        <TextBlock Text="Image2  " />
        <TextBlock Text="Image3  " />
        <TextBlock Text="Image4  " />
        <TextBlock Text="Image5  " />
        <TextBlock Text="Image6  " />
        <TextBlock Text="Image7  " />
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

In the ListBox' Loaded event, we use VisualTreeHelper to search through its [Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242) and find its built-in ScrollViewer. Once we find it, we hook it up to the two buttons we created:

```
private void OnMyListLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scroller = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(_myList, 0), 0) as ScrollViewer;
    if (scroller != null)
    {
        _prev.Command = ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand;
        _prev.CommandTarget = scroller;

        _next.Command = ScrollBar.LineRightCommand;
        _next.CommandTarget = scroller;

        scroller.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: The name "ScrollBar." does not exist in the current context...Do i need to import any references?

Comment: @0070 - You don't need any new references, but you need another "using" statement along with the other using statements at the top of your code file: **using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;**

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <Button Name="LeftB" Grid.Column="0" />
     <Button Name="RightB" Grid.Column="2" />
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="Images" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

The images can be the Children of the StackPanel.
Of course you should set the size of the the images as a function of their number and StackPanel's Width. The best way might be to handle Width change event of the StackPanel.